# How to make a date's month be capitalized while inserting data into a SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, date, formatting

I am inserting data into tables and have come across an issue. I am needing the date to be: "29-SEP-2000", but am getting "29-Sep-2000". Any help would be much appreciated!

```
INSERT INTO movies (title_id, title, description, rating, category, release_date)
VALUES
(title_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Being the Ricardos', 'Follows Lucy and Desi as they face a crisis that could end their careers and another that could end their marriage.', 'R', 'DRAMA', (TO_DATE('December 2, 2021', 'Mon DD, YYYY')));
```

Comment: https://database.guide/capitalization-of-day-and-month-names-when-formatting-dates-in-oracle/

Comment: @JonasMetzler Thank you for this link! Unfortunately, when i do this i get an error saying: 'ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected'

Comment: use to_char(release_date,'dd-MON-yyyy')  the uppercase "MON" is important

Comment: @PaulMaxwell That was what I was thinking I needed to do, but when I do this, I get "ORA-01722: invalid number". Release Date is of data type, so i assume that is why..

Comment: You say "I am getting" "29-Sep-2000". That is not correct. You're seeing "29-Sep-2000" because the nls_date_format settings on your clients have that format. Dates are not stored as the date strings, they're stored internally as numbers and how the date is displayed is determined by the client settings. If you want to see another format, use TO_CHAR in your query to let oracle know what format you want.

Comment: What's the data type of `release_date`, and what's the result of `select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter='NLS_DATE_FORMAT';`?

Comment: @FatP release_date is the DATE datatype, this is what I get when I ran that statement: VALUE dd-Mon-yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong approach.

Dates aren't stored in "uppercase" nor "lowercase"; Oracle uses 7 bytes to store that info in its internal format. All you have to do is to insert a valid `DATE` datatype value:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE movies
  2  (
  3     title_id       NUMBER,
  4     title          VARCHAR2 (30),
  5     description    VARCHAR2 (200),
  6     rating         VARCHAR2 (5),
  7     category       VARCHAR2 (20),
  8     release_date   DATE
  9  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE title_id_seq;

Sequence created.
```

Insert: note the `release_date` value - I used date literal which always looks like that: `date` keyword followed by value in `yyyy-mm-dd` format enclosed into single quotes.

```
SQL> INSERT INTO movies (title_id,
  2                      title,
  3                      description,
  4                      rating,
  5                      category,
  6                      release_date)
  7       VALUES (title_id_seq.NEXTVAL,
  8               'Being the Ricardos',
  9               'Follows Lucy and Desi ...',
 10               'R',
 11               'DRAMA',
 12               DATE '2021-12-02');

1 row created.
```

Date could've also been `to_date` function with appropriate format mask, e.g.

```
SQL> update movies set release_date = to_date('02.12.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy');

1 row updated.

SQL> update movies set release_date = to_date('2021, Dec 02', 'yyyy, Mon dd', 'nls_date_language=english');

1 row updated.
```

All those values represent the same date: 2nd of December 2021.

It is up to **you** to present that value any way you want. How? By applying `TO_CHAR` function with desired format model.

By default, in **my** database (which means that yours might display it differently), it looks like this:

```
SQL> select release_date from movies;

RELEASE_
--------
02.12.21
```

The way you wanted it:

```
SQL> select to_char(release_date, 'MON dd, yyyy') release_date from movies;

RELEASE_DATE
------------
DEC 02, 2021
```

---

Error you posted in a comment (ORA-01722: invalid number) has nothing to do with dates; it is related to *something different*. Can't tell what; it is raised when you try to insert a character into a `NUMBER` datatype column. Are you sure you matched column names and appropriate data types in your `INSERT` statement? Because, everything works OK with **my** sample table.

Comment: Correct date data type is part of the provided insert e.g. `(TO_DATE('December 2, 2021', 'Mon DD, YYYY')));`

Comment: That's not really correct. "December" is not "Mon" but "Month". But that's not the point here; the point is that you insert valid DATE datatype value, and then **present** it any way you want.

Comment: yes, and that is the issue I believe, although not really clear

Comment: Did you carefully read what I wrote in the answer? I believe I explained everything.

Comment: First off, thank you so much for your time, this has been bothering me for hours! So what you're saying is that I do not have to format date when inserting it into a table? You're a life saver!!

Correct me if I'm wrong, so i would just do this:
INSERT INTO movies (title_id, title, description, rating, category, release_date)
VALUES
(title_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Being the Ricardos', 'Follows Lucy and Desi as they face a crisis that could end their careers and another that could end their marriage.', 'R', 'DRAMA', DATE '2021-12-02');

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, that's what you should insert - a valid DATE datatype value. Then, when you'll write some kind of a "report" to show data to end users, you'll display date in format they want. Use TO_CHAR function and apply model users specified, e.g. DD.MM.YYYY or DD Mon, YYYY or ...